# PByteArray to TMemoryStream and reverse

Tags: delphi

I have the following code. I am trying to do a calculation on the data pointed by buf.

```
buf:PByteArray
inmem,outmem:TmemoryStream;
...
size := GetFileSize(aFile, nil);
buf := MapViewOfFile(map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

inmem.SetSize(size);
inmem.Position := 0;

//buf to memorystream
inmem.Write(buf[0], size);
outmem := tmemorystream.Create;
outmem.SetSize(size);

//Do memory stream processing
ProcMemoryStreams(inmem,outmem,size);
//

outmem.Position:=0;
//memorystream to buf
outmem.Read(buf[0],size); <-Access violation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) what is ProcMemoryStreams ? what it does ? 2) what do you want to achieve ? http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal 3) what is the exact text of error - copy it here.

Comment: My blind bet is that you 1) should remove `inmem.SetSize(size);` line and 2) should add `inmem := TMemoryStream.Create();` line instead. Another possible reason 3) is that `MapViewOfFile(map` is smaller than `GetFileSize(aFile`. Or 4) `ProcMemoryStreams` corrupts any of its three parameters... or anything at all, too little data

Comment: Also...this is a memory leak waiting to happen... your Stream Creates need to have a try finally...unless you can guarantee that they will get freed...(which try finally does)

Comment: That was a code fragment, so I didn't put in the create or try statements. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to write to read-only buffer

```
buf := MapViewOfFile(map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0); //read-only flag HERE!
...
outmem.Read(buf[0],size);  //writing to read-only memory region
```

so add `FILE_MAP_WRITE` flag (and don't forget about access flag in CreateFileMapping)

Comment: This would be better if it was formatted more nicely. Could you arrange that please? Still, +1

Comment: Of course. Is there any method to use code formatting and some word emphasis (like bold in regular text) simultaneously?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Your edit is good though. I think that's a better compromise.

Comment: The code works fine after add write flags where appropriate. If I don't want the changes to be written to the disk file, how should I change the code?

Comment: Got it using WRITECOPY flags when mapping. The modified PByteArray is used later in the code so outmem.read is required. The PAGE_WRITECOPY and FILE_MAP_COPY flags creates a mapping where the changes are not written to file. Thank you.